# I can't auto answer yes in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I create batch file like this in **Windows7** but it can't delete file.

```
echo y | DEL autorun.inf
echo y | DEL autorun.ini
```

when I run this code it show like this but not delete any file.

> N:>echo y   | DEL autorun.inf N:\autorun.inf*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
>
> N:>echo y   | DEL autorun.ini N:\autorun.ini*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

It seem type yes but not enter

How to auto answer yes in batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `/f` flag to force the deletion of readonly files, and `/q` flag for quiet mode (no delete confirmation)

```
echo DEL /f /q autorun.inf
echo DEL /f /q autorun.ini
```

Comment: I try to use like this **echo DEL /f /q autorun.inf**
 , **echo y | DEL autorun.inf /Q** , **echo DEL autorun.inf /f /q** , **DEL autorun.inf /f /q**  But also can't delete anyfile .

Comment: I use your code it show like this in cmd  `N:\>echo DEL /f /q autorun.inf
DEL /f /q autorun.inf

N:\>echo DEL /f /q autorun.ini
DEL /f /q autorun.ini`  but not delete file

Comment: Perhaps it could be a good idea to remove the `echo`, else you only display `DEL /f /q autorun.inf` instead of deleting it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo y | DEL autorun.inf /Q
```

/Q will not ask for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Y | del "C:\Packages_Auto_Download\EIR\17\IB01" /Q
```

Above command will work without any issue with proper deletion.